# Filtering and retrying until the fiter passes, with passed items not being retested

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Given a list of items that represent some externally mutable resource how can I filter the list to emit only certain items and wait for all items to obey the filter?

More concretely: from a list of files, build a `Flowable` that filters by existence, only allowing ones through that exist. If they don't exist, wait 5s for the files to exist.

Here's my first attempt:

```
Flowable.fromArray(new File("/tmp/file-1"), new File("/tmp/file-2"))
    .map(f -> {
        boolean exists = f.exists();
        System.out.println(f.getName() + " exists? " + exists);
        if(exists) {
            return f;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(f.getName() + " doesn't exist");
        }
    })
    .retryWhen(ft -> {
        return ft.flatMap(error -> Flowable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    })
    .blockingForEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getName() + " exists!"));
```

However this gives:

```
file-1 exists? false
file-1 exists? false
file-1 exists? false
file-1 exists? false  ** $ touch /tmp/file-1 **
file-1 exists? true
file-2 exists? false
file-1 exists!
file-1 exists? true   ** BAD we are retesting! **
file-2 exists? false
file-1 exists!        ** BAD the subscriber got a duplicate event! **
```

Even if I add a `distinct` after the `retryWhen` the file is still retested.

So is there a way of only retesting those items that failed the previous test (without using mutable state outside of the `Observable`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `retryWhen` on an inner sequence and `flatMap` them together:

```java
source
.flatMap(file -> 
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        if (file.exists()) {
            return file;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
    })
    .retryWhen(errors -> errors.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
)
.blockingForEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getName() + " exists!"));
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works nicely. Sorry it took a while to test this. Why did you use  `fromCallable` rather than a simple `just` on the inner observable? (I'm trying to learn!)

Comment: Think. If you throw in the `flatMap`'s lambda, you break the whole sequence.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes I didn't fully explain myself. I meant use `just` then `map` for the `exists` test. I like to try to collapse the calls to the simplest computations possible.

Comment: Try it an see if you find it simpler.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I was just wondered if there was some philosophical reason or something non-obvious (e.g. application to a wider range of use cases). Thanks again.